Confusion with correct way to call Observable?
I am seeing that there may be two ways to call a Class from other Views or Models.
The following is what I have created:
import Foundation
import Observation

@Observable 
class User {
    var EmailAddress = ""
    var Password = ""
}

And have seen it called either:
@State var user: User

or
@State var user = User()

This one is the preferred?

Apple clear state here Managing model data in your app that you should use @State private var user = User() when you use the @Observable class. Quote "...declare a private variable and initialize it with a instance of an observable data model type."
Here however, Monitoring data Apple state clearly
that you shouls use @StateObject private var ... when you use the older ObservableObject class.

State should always be private.

@Fritzables I'm not quite sure what you mean by the phrase “call observable”. Do you mean how to correctly create an instance of an @Observable class as a state in a view? Your examples are somewhat confusing, as the first one is only valid if the state property is created in the init method of the view itself. @State wrapped properties must never be injected into a view from outside, which is why those properties should always be declared as private.

This question is poorly put together. Yes, you are correct in your comments with respect to how I have put the words together.   I assumed that the reader would understand what I meant. I guess I need to better understand the syntax of Swift and understand better my own question.

The second one with private access control is the correct way to use @State / @StateObject.
After Observation
Since user class no longer had to conform to ObservableObject. @StateObject -> @State is sufficient.
@State private var user = User()


Before Observation
According to Apple documentations about @State and @StateObject:

Even for a configurable state object, you still declare it as private. This ensures that you can’t accidentally set the parameter through a memberwise initializer of the view, because doing so can conflict with the framework’s storage management and produce unexpected results.

So, it should be @StateObject, since you stored an Object rather than a single property.
@StateObject private var user = User()

Notice: you're still allowed to use @State in this circumstance. However, the view that listened to the state object will only re-render if the reference to the object changes, instead of updating when these @Published properties change.

From documentation: "If you need to store a value type, like a structure, string, or integer, use the State property wrapper instead. Also use State if you need to store a reference type that conforms to the Observable() protocol. To learn more about Observation in SwiftUI, see Managing model data in your app."

@State var user = User() causes unnecessary heap allocations that will slow down SwiftUI (a bit like a memory leak) when User is a class so you certainly should not use that. The reason is every time the View is init a new User object will be init and lost. Its just how State works, a new initial value is init regardless if it already has one, which isn't an issue for memory stack values but is a big problem for heap objects. Avoiding unnecessary heap allocations is mentioned in Demystify SwiftUI performance WWDC 2023 at 3:18.
You can actually still use @StateObject and make the class conform to ObservableObject but just don't have any @Published properties.
However, in the docs it suggests to use an optional @State, e.g.
@State var user: User?

The reason is explained in the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

A State property always instantiates its default value when SwiftUI
instantiates the view. For this reason, avoid side effects and
performance-intensive work when initializing the default value. For
example, if a view updates frequently, allocating a new default object
each time the view initializes can become expensive. Instead, you can
defer the creation of the object using the task(priority:_:) modifier,
which is called only once when the view first appears:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var library: Library?


    var body: some View {
        LibraryView(library: library)
            .task {
                library = Library()
            }
    }
}

Delaying the creation of the observable state object ensures that unnecessary allocations of the object doesn’t happen each
time SwiftUI initializes the view. Using the task(priority:_:)
modifier is also an effective way to defer any other kind of work
required to create the initial state of the view, such as network
calls or file access.

Note, .onAppear is better suited to doing this job since we don't need an async context just to init an object. If the UI reappears you might want to check for nil so you don't init multiple times. You might also want to set it to nil in .onDisappear too to be certain the memory is freed, SwiftUI can be quite greedy on memory with objects. So something like:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var library: Library?

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let library {
                LibraryView(library: library)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if library == nil {
                 library = Library()
            }
        }
        .onDissapear {
            library = nil
        }
    }
}

This is all a big mess and might not even work, so I think it is best to just continue to use @StateObject or try to not even need an object, e.g. use .task with structs that contain async funcs that return results.

The use of a reference type via a State property wrapper does not cause a memory leak. This may appear to be the case at first glance, but it is not true because SwiftUI does not release the memory of state variables immediately, but at certain points in time / after certain actions. Also note that Apple itself describes that the use of reference types per State is permitted: "Also use State if you need to store a reference type that conforms to the Observable() protocol."

That doc was written when it was possible but now it is a memory leak because they removed autoclosure from State init probably because it broke it for structs. It was only in for a few betas when they were working on Observable but it failed so they removed it. So we have to use StateObject, It is odd they haven’t updated the docs though.

The init behavior of State when used with a reference type is something to be aware of and is also documented by Apple. But again, this does not cause a memory leak. Your statement is simply wrong and it can be proven wrong with a simple demo. A memory leak would mean that the reference would never be released.

Geez oh, ok fine I edit it to say "like a memory leak".
